# How to click a link programatically using id.click() inside php?

Tags: javascript, php, click

In this code first script executes but second script doesn't execute.

```
<?php
    echo "<script>
        document.getElementById('pageOne').click();
      </script>"; // This doesn't execute
      
    echo "<script>
        alert('Unknown user');
      </script>"; // This executes
    
 ?>
```

Comment: `first script executes but second script doesn't execute`...what you've written in the comments next to each code snippet contradicts this. Which way round is correct? Please [edit] the question to clarify it. Also please provide a [mre] of the issue...we can't see what the "pageOne" HTML element is or where it exists in your page, and thus cannot predict what would happen if you click it.

Comment: P.S. Why would you make PHP echo these simple script tags? You don't need PHP for that. Simply close the PHP tags, paste them as literal text and the browser will duly load them as-is. Then open your PHP tags again later on if you need to write more PHP code. The result is much cleaner and easier to read, and less liable to silly issues with things like escaping of quote marks etc.

Comment: Is that `pageOne` element already loaded when you try to click it?

Comment: @brombeer This was it!. The form id wasn't loaded where I was calling the function. Moved the php code to the bottom of `body`. Now it works fine

Comment: @brombeer Add it as answer so that I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element was not loaded where I was calling the click() function. Moving the php script to bottom of body did the work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).